# Query to find Employees who have taken more than their eligible leave with respect to their Job Roles

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have these tables with the following columns :

```
Employee24( EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, GENDER, JOBROLES);

Leave25( EMPLOYEEID,LEAVEID, LEAVETYPE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE);

JOBROLESELIGIBLELE(JOBROLES, ELIGIBLE_SICK_LEAVES, ELIGIBLE_EARNED_LEAVES)
```

I want to write a query to find employees who have taken more than eleigible leaves with respect to jobroles

```
SELECT * 
  FROM EMPLOYEE24 
  WHERE EMPLOYEEID IN (SELECT EMPLOYEEID 
                        FROM LEAVE25 L WHERE (STARTDATE-ENDDATE)
    < (SELECT ELIGIBLE_SICK_LEAVES + ELIGIBLE_EARNED_LEAVES 
              FROM  JOBROLESELIGIBELE 
              GROUP BY JOBROLES));
```

Comment: Please turn your Caps Lock off!

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and the definition of your terms would help.

Comment: What are the table's primary keys? Is it `Employee24(EmployeeId)`, Leave25(EmployeeId,LeaveId)` and `JobRolesEligibele(JobRoles)`?

Comment: @Thorsten Kethner yes right.

Comment: The datamodel seems a bit off. I suppose that LEAVETYPE indicates ELIGIBLE_SICK_LEAVES, ELIGIBLE_EARNED_LEAVES (and the accepted answer supports this assumption). That should not be the case. Either use columns for different leave types in all tables or use rows for different `LEAVETYPE`. Don't mix the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find each user that has exceeded the leave amount for each type of leave:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/955da/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee24( EMPLOYEEID, JOBROLES ) AS
SELECT 1, 'RoleA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'RoleB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'RoleB' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Leave25( EMPLOYEEID,LEAVEID, LEAVETYPE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE) AS
SELECT 1,1,'SickLeave',  DATE '2018-01-01', DATE '2018-01-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,'SickLeave',  DATE '2018-01-21', DATE '2018-01-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3,'EarnedLeave',DATE '2018-01-11', DATE '2018-01-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,4,'EarnedLeave',DATE '2018-02-01', DATE '2018-02-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,5,'EarnedLeave',DATE '2018-02-21', DATE '2018-03-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,6,'EarnedLeave',DATE '2018-02-01', DATE '2018-02-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,7,'SickLeave',  DATE '2018-01-01', DATE '2018-01-09' FROM DUAL;


CREATE TABLE JOBROLESELIGIBLELE(JOBROLES, ELIGIBLE_SICK_LEAVES, ELIGIBLE_EARNED_LEAVES) AS
SELECT 'RoleA', 14, 24 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RoleB',  7, 10 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT e.employeeId,
       l.leavetype,
       l.days_leave,
       r.AllowedLeaveAmount
FROM   Employee24 e
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT employeeId,
                SUM( enddate - startdate ) AS days_leave,
                leavetype
         FROM   Leave25
         GROUP BY employeeId, leaveType
       ) l
       ON ( e.employeeId = l.employeeId )
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT *
         FROM   JobRolesEligibleLE
         UNPIVOT ( AllowedLeaveAmount FOR LeaveType IN (
           Eligible_Sick_Leaves   AS 'SickLeave',
           Eligible_Earned_Leaves AS 'EarnedLeave'
         ) )
       ) r
       ON (    l.leavetype = r.leavetype
           AND e.jobroles   = r.jobroles )
WHERE  l.days_leave > r.AllowedLeaveAmount
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/955da/1/0)**:

```
| EMPLOYEEID |   LEAVETYPE | DAYS_LEAVE | ALLOWEDLEAVEAMOUNT |
|------------|-------------|------------|--------------------|
|          1 |   SickLeave |         20 |                 14 |
|          1 | EarnedLeave |         30 |                 24 |
|          2 | EarnedLeave |         12 |                 10 |
|          3 |   SickLeave |          8 |                  7 |
```