# a query to display names of employees, leaves taken, leaves eligible and percentage

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have these tables with the following columns :

```
   Employee24( EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, GENDER, JOBROLES);

   Leave25( EMPLOYEEID,LEAVEID, LEAVETYPE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE);

  JOBROLESELIGIBLELE(JOBROLES, ELIGIBLE_SICK_LEAVES, ELIGIBLE_EARNED_LEAVES)
```

I want to write a query to display names of employees, leaves taken, leaves eligible and percentage

```
        SELECT * 
  FROM EMPLOYEE24 
  WHERE EMPLOYEEID IN (SELECT EMPLOYEEID 
                        FROM LEAVE25 L WHERE (STARTDATE-ENDDATE) AS "TAKENLEAVE"
    < (SELECT (ELIGIBLE_SICK_LEAVES + ELIGIBLE_EARNED_LEAVES) AS "ELIGIBLELEAVE"
              ,TAKENLEAVE/ELIGIBLELEAVE * 100
              FROM  JOBROLESELIGIBELE));
```

Sample data :
           CREATE TABLE Employee24( EMPLOYEEID, JOBROLES ) AS
           SELECT 1, 'RoleA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
           SELECT 2, 'RoleB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
           SELECT 3, 'RoleB' FROM DUAL;

```
       CREATE TABLE Leave25( EMPLOYEEID,LEAVEID, LEAVETYPE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE) AS
       SELECT 1,1,'SickLeave',  DATE '2018-01-01', DATE '2018-01-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL   
       SELECT 1,2,'SickLeave',  DATE '2018-01-21', DATE '2018-01-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 1,3,'EarnedLeave',DATE '2018-01-11', DATE '2018-01-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 1,4,'EarnedLeave',DATE '2018-02-01', DATE '2018-02-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 1,5,'EarnedLeave',DATE '2018-02-21', DATE '2018-03-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 2,6,'EarnedLeave',DATE '2018-02-01', DATE '2018-02-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 3,7,'SickLeave',  DATE '2018-01-01', DATE '2018-01-09' FROM DUAL;


      CREATE TABLE JOBROLESELIGIBLELE(JOBROLES, ELIGIBLE_SICK_LEAVES, ELIGIBLE_EARNED_LEAVES) AS
      SELECT 'RoleA', 14, 24 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'RoleB',  7, 10 FROM DUAL;
```

EXPECTED RESULT :
      EMPLOYEEID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | LEAVESTAKEN | ELIGIBLELEAVES | PERCENTAGE

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help convey what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sample data and expected results added. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A small change to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602239/query-to-find-employees-who-have-taken-more-than-their-eligible-leave-with-respe/50602661#50602661):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90b64/11)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee24( EMPLOYEEID, JOBROLES ) AS
SELECT 1, 'RoleA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'RoleB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'RoleB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'RoleA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'RoleB' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Leave25( EMPLOYEEID,LEAVEID, LEAVETYPE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE) AS
SELECT 1,1,'SickLeave',  DATE '2018-01-01', DATE '2018-01-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,'SickLeave',  DATE '2018-01-21', DATE '2018-01-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3,'EarnedLeave',DATE '2018-01-11', DATE '2018-01-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,4,'EarnedLeave',DATE '2018-02-01', DATE '2018-02-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,5,'EarnedLeave',DATE '2018-02-21', DATE '2018-03-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,6,'EarnedLeave',DATE '2018-02-01', DATE '2018-02-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,7,'SickLeave',  DATE '2018-01-01', DATE '2018-01-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,8,'EarnedLeave',DATE '2018-02-01', DATE '2018-02-11' FROM DUAL;


CREATE TABLE JOBROLESELIGIBLELE(JOBROLES, ELIGIBLE_SICK_LEAVES, ELIGIBLE_EARNED_LEAVES) AS
SELECT 'RoleA', 14, 24 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RoleB',  7, 10 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT e.employeeId,
       r.leavetype,
       COALESCE( l.days_leave, 0 ) AS days_leave,
       r.AllowedLeaveAmount,
       100 * COALESCE( l.days_leave, 0 ) / r.AllowedLeaveAmount As leave_percent 
FROM   Employee24 e
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT *
         FROM   JobRolesEligibleLE
         UNPIVOT ( AllowedLeaveAmount FOR LeaveType IN (
           Eligible_Sick_Leaves   AS 'SickLeave',
           Eligible_Earned_Leaves AS 'EarnedLeave'
         ) )
       ) r
       ON ( e.jobroles   = r.jobroles )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       ( SELECT employeeId,
                SUM( enddate - startdate ) AS days_leave,
                leavetype
         FROM   Leave25
         GROUP BY employeeId, leaveType
       ) l
       ON (   e.employeeId = l.employeeId
          AND l.leavetype = r.leavetype )
ORDER BY employeeId, LeaveType
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90b64/11/0)**:

```
| EMPLOYEEID |   LEAVETYPE | DAYS_LEAVE | ALLOWEDLEAVEAMOUNT |      LEAVE_PERCENT |
|------------|-------------|------------|--------------------|--------------------|
|          1 | EarnedLeave |         30 |                 24 |                125 |
|          1 |   SickLeave |         20 |                 14 | 142.85714285714286 |
|          2 | EarnedLeave |         12 |                 10 |                120 |
|          2 |   SickLeave |          0 |                  7 |                  0 |
|          3 | EarnedLeave |          0 |                 10 |                  0 |
|          3 |   SickLeave |          8 |                  7 | 114.28571428571429 |
|          4 | EarnedLeave |          0 |                 24 |                  0 |
|          4 |   SickLeave |          0 |                 14 |                  0 |
|          5 | EarnedLeave |         10 |                 10 |                100 |
|          5 |   SickLeave |          0 |                  7 |                  0 |
```

Comment: with this every record in daysleave column and percentage column is showing zero

Comment: @user2147357 Please provide a [MCVE] that demonstrates the issue as the SQLFiddle clearly shows that those columns are not all zero for my data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use aliases in the list of columns to address a column, you have to use the full expression. And you cannot introduce aliases on columns in the `WHERE` clause.

Maybe you want something like this:

```
SELECT E.FIRSTNAME,
       E.LASTNAME,
       (SELECT SUM(L.STARTDATE - L.ENDDATE)
               FROM LEAVE25 L
               WHERE L.EMPLOYEEID = E.EMPLOYEEEID) "TAKENLEAVE",
       J.ELIGIBLE_SICK_LEAVES + J.ELIGIBLE_EARNED_LEAVES "ELIGIBLELEAVE",
       (SELECT SUM(L.STARTDATE - L.ENDDATE)
               FROM LEAVE25 L
               WHERE L.EMPLOYEEID = E.EMPLOYEEEID)
       /
       (J.ELIGIBLE_SICK_LEAVES + J.ELIGIBLE_EARNED_LEAVES)
       * 100 "PERCENTAGE"
       FROM EMPLOYEE24 E
            LEFT JOIN JOBROLESELIGIBLELE J
                      ON J.JOBROLES = E.JOBROLES;
```